# Fastest way to apply function on different lists in python

Tags: python, algorithm, parallel-processing

I have complex algorithm to build in order to select the best combination of elements in my list.

I have a list of 20 elements. I make all the combinations this list using this algorithms, the resutlt would be a list of element with size:  2^20-1 (without duplications)

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_all_combinations(input_list):
    for i in xrange(len(input_list)):
        for item in combinations(input_list, r = i + 1):
            yield list(item)    

input_list = [1,4,6,8,11,13,5,98,45,10,21,34,46,85,311,133,35,938,345,310]
print  len(get_all_combinations(input_list)) # 1048575
```

I have another algorithm that is applied on every list, then calculate the max.

```
// this is just an example
def calcul_factor(item):
 return max(item) * min(item) / sqrt(min(item))
```

I tried to do it like this way: but it's taking a long time.

```
columnsList= get_all_combinations(input_list)
for x in columnsList:
  i= calcul_factor(x)
  factorsList.append(i)
  l.append(x)


print "max", max(factorsList)
print "Best combinations:", l[factorsList.index( max(factorsList))]
```

Does using Maps/Lamda expressions solve issues to make "parallelisme" to calculate the maximum ?
ANy hints to do that ?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve with this? There is almost certainly a better algorithm.

Comment: The best solution to your problem will probably be to redesign your algorithm so you don't need to do 20 factorial things.

Comment: Actually, you're not doing 20 factorial things. You've either miscalculated the number of possibilities you need to consider or misimplemented `get_all_combinations`. You're only considering 2^20-1 combinations, because you only consider each combination in a single order.

Comment: @user2357112: he actually has calculated it correctly (per comment at the end of the first code block) but describes it wrongly, as you note.

Comment: Sorry!it's my bad. What solution are you mentioning by re-designing the algorithm ?

Comment: @user3378649: we can't figure out what the best algorithm would be unless you tell us the real problem; different problems will have different best solutions.

Comment: the problem is not related to combinators' generation, but to applying "Calcul Factor" on every item in the list. I don't wanna go one by one in columnsList, but somehow iterate them in parallel way. Can I do that using map/lamda like: l= map(columnsList, calcul_factor)

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't find a better algorithm (which might be needed here) you can avoid creating those big lists by using generators.
With the help of `itertools.chain` you can combine the `itertools.combinations`-generators. Furthermore the `max`-function can take a function as a key.
Your code can be reduced to:

```
all_combinations = chain(*[combinations(input_list, i) for i in range(1, len(input_list))])
max(all_combinations, key=algorithm)
```

Since this code relies solely on generators it might be faster (doesn't mean fast enough).

Edit: I generally agree with Hugh Bothwell, that you should be trying to find a better algorithm before going with an implementation like this. Especially if your lists are going to contain more than 20 elements.

Comment: what about using map like : l= map(columnsList, calcul_factor)

Comment: 'cause the problem is not related to combinators' generation, but to applying "Calcul Factor" on every item in the list.

Comment: @user3378649: that sort of implementation improvement may yield a 2- or 3-times speed-up (or none at all). A better algorithm can yield a million-times speed-up. Which would you rather pursue first?

Comment: Do you need the result for each combination or just the combination with the maximum value? In the first case you can use ``map(algorithm, all_combinations)`` and convert that to a list or something.

Comment: I need the the combination of the maximum value?

Comment: @user3378649: so show us how you determine "maximum value", so we can find shortcuts!

Comment: I am adding the rresult every time to factorsList, then calculate the max at the end. check the obove-mentioned code. meanwhile, I add in the list the combinations, after finding the max, I use the index to get the combination

Comment: ``max(all_combinations, key=algorithm)`` returns the combination with the highest value calculated with ``algorithm``

Comment: @user3378649: I phrased that badly; "maximum" is easy, I want to know how you calculate "value" (ie what is `algorithm`, in @Bengt's phrasing). There may be a significantly better method than simply trying every combination.

Answer (score 0):

If you can easily calculate `calcul_factor(item + [k])` given `calcul_factor(item)`, you might greatly benefit from a dynamic-programming approach.

If you can eliminate some bad solutions early, it will also greatly reduce the total number of combinations to consider (branch-and-bound).

If the calculation is reasonably well-behaved, you might even be able to use ie simplex method or a linear solver and walk directly to a solution (something like `O(n**2 log n)` runtime instead of `O(2**n))`

Could you show us the *actual* `calcul_factor` code and an *actual* `input_list`?

Comment: calcul_factor is to apply a special mathematical formula. It's a long operation that I am working on. but has the entry which (parameters: can be one or many elements). This is the aim behind this algorithm, finding the best combinations of these elements.  what do you mean by dynamic-programming approach

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming for an overview; basically it lets you amortize your calculation by storing partial solutions and building on the partials to find a full solution.

Comment: ... and if your calculation is not yet complete, or possibly even fully understood, worrying about multithreading is premature. "First, make it work; then make it work faster".